# How to get a URL from HTML code block?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

I have the following code :

```
<?php $a= "<a href="http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-6331466-10751223" target="_top">
<img src="http://www.tqlkg.com/image-6331466-10751223" width="300" height="250" alt="Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2013" border="0"/></a>" ?>
```

Please suggest me any Idea that how can I retrieve the URL (http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-6331466-10751223) in php.

Comment: Do you have this in a string ? Is that in your current PHP file ?

Comment: what have u tried so far!!! can u show ur code

Comment: @soul I don't have any Idea what should I try

Comment: Depends on actual scenario. You can `preg_match` too.

Comment: You realise you'll get an error here because of unescaped quotation marks (") here right?

Comment: This can be done using DOM.Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element

Answer (score 4):

If you're parsing HTML to extract href attribute values from anchor tags, use an HTML/DOM Parser (definitely don't use regex).

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369147/javascript-regex-to-extract-anchor-text-and-url-from-anchor-tags)

[PHP XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977756/extract-url-using-php)

OR

[Don't use regexes to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use the PHP DOM:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str); // Your string

//get all anchors
$anchors = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');

//display all hrefs
for ($i = 0; $i < $anchors->length; $i++)
    echo $anchors->item($i)->getAttribute('href') . "<br />";
```

You can check if the node has a `href` using `hasAttribute()` first if necessary.

and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977756/extract-url-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try either `jquery` or `DOMXPATH`

Here's the link to [DOMXPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730642/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-href-attribute)

Using Jquery, you can get its value by putting a selector to it, say `id`,

```
<a href="http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-6331466-10751223" target="_top" id='url'>
```

And, then access it as,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var link = $("#url").attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use a regular expression:

```
preg_match("/href=\"(http:\/\/.*)\"/U",$a, $matches);
```

It will search for text between 'href="' and '"'
$matches[1] will contain your url.